# Details about cumulative hotfix installation for Sitecore 10.1.0 version

Tags: installation, packages

I'm trying to install the `cumulative hotfix:` https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001300 for Sitecore 10.1.0 version.

Hotfix contains `WDP Packages` .Can you please share details about the `installation` process for WDP Packages in xp single and xp scaled topologies?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find details in the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/deploy-a-sitecore-xp-pre-release-to-a-paas-solution.html

If you initially deployed using the Sitecore Azure Toolkit and the ARM template (https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/blob/master/Sitecore%2010.2.0/XP/azuredeploy.parameters.json) then you can replace the WDP references to reference the cumulative update instead of the packages for the initial installation and then redeploy - this will update the deployed version of Sitecore XP to the version with the cumulative updates applied.

The ARM template is designed to be *idempotent* so redeploying wont remove and then reinstate the resources, as the resources are already there then the deployment only needs to install the packages.

Note that the documentation specifies: "When you deploy a pre-release to a Sitecore XP PaaS solution, the App Service Plans may have changes since your last deployment. We therefore recommend that you update your deployment scripts and ARM templates to use the latest App Service Plans."

For an XP Single (XP0) instance that you might be running locally, you can use `msdeploy.exe` to deploy the package where you set `-source` as the location of the `scwdp` package - you will have to do this for each role.

Comment: Thanks @Calum for sharing the details.

Comment: we tried deploying the wdp packages but the deployment failed with the error "Another certificate exists with same thumbprint". Is there a way to keep the existing setup as it is and deploy new WDP packages on top of the current installation?

Comment: @AnjaliPrathipati - if you use the ARM template you used to provision the original environment then you should be able to run that again but with updated package URLs to point at the cumulative updates instead of the original scwdp files.